# How to use google-api to upload image on client side.?

Tags: java, php, asp.net, .net, google-api

I have search for google-api-client but no output....

We are given the facility to upload image on client side,
when the user click on upload button, then user should redirect to google.
Search on google for image and then the user should be able to select that image.
(Wants to do it in any language)

Comment: it's easy, do you want someone to write code for you, right? or it's better to provide the links for tutorials, as you can't search yourself? please, clarify.

Comment: when user will upload image on client side say suppose book's image with title "India of my dreams" then that link should go to google and he finds no of images for his title(India of my dreams) he will select one from it and upload... means i want in my project a facility to link to google so that user will not upload their image but the image that is available on google search engine??? am i clear now